# Can I output data from other table's column that meet the specific criteria to show in the single row

Tags: sql-server

I'm currently learning SQL using SSMS 2014 and I was wondering is it possible to make a SELECT statement so that it will join the two tables but in such a way that data from the second table is shown in the separate columns for the different values certain criteria is met, so that the output is shown in the same row?

I am not sure how to paraphrase this question properly so I will give an example.

For example if we have 2 tables:

```
ProductID    ProductName    More columns...
---------    -----------    ...
1            Shoes          ...
2            Shirt          ...
```

```
Product    Color    Amount
-------    -----    ------
1          Black    5
1          Red      3
2          Black    1
2          Red      6
2          White    3
```

I want the select statement to return something like this:

```
 
ProductName    Col:Black    Col:Red    Col:White
-----------    ---------    -------    ---------
Shoes          5            3          NULL
Shirt          1            6          3
```

How can I make such query and is it even possible in T-SQL? Is there a way to specify IF statement in SQL such that it return date if some condition is met.

So far I am only able to get output like this but it's not what i want:

```
Product    Color    Amount
-------    -----    ------
Shoes      Black    5
Shoes      Red      3
Shirt      Black    1
Shirt      Red      6
Shirt      White    3
```

Comment: Google:  "SQL Server pivot"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with conditional aggregation using CASE EXPRESSION :

```
SELECT t.productName,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.Color = 'Black' then s.amount end) as Col_Black,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.Color = 'Red' then s.amount end) as Col_Red,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.Color = 'White' then s.amount end) as Col_White
       ..........
FROM Table1 t
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 s
 ON(t.productID = s.product)
GROUP BY t.productName
```

Comment: It worked thank you, but the only thing I don't get is why the CASE expression is enclosed in the MAX function?

Comment: Because if not, then the results would be Shoes,5,null ,null . Shoes , null, 6, null ETC... Thats why the max and the group by clause, to unite them into one row @Pawel